# Idiomatic way to bind to whether an ObservableCollection is empty?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to make an element visible depending on whether an `ObservableCollection` (used elsewhere) is empty. Traditionally, if you need visual changes to reflect an elaborate condition on an exposed property of the view model, if you bind to that property, and use a converter, so that property change notifications trigger the evaluation of the converter and the view updates.

But in this instance, this doesn't work: changes in the `ObservableCollection` trigger `CollectionChanged`, not `PropertyChanged`, as they should - the collection wasn't replaced. But the binding for a non-`ItemsSource` property expects `PropertyChanged` events as trigger.

Of course I can think of a few dirty hacks based on listening to `CollectionChanged` myself, but is there a clean way to do this ?

Comment: You could bind to `collection.Count` (with a suitable converter). When items are added or removed this is also reported by a `PropertyChanged` on the `Count` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the visibility to the count property of the ObservableCollection and use a converter, that converts an integer to Visibility. Visibility should be Hidden when number ( or Count ) is zero.

Something like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Visibility))]
public sealed class HideWhenZeroConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
     object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
     if (value is not int number)
       return null;

     return number == 0 ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
     object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
     throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<ListBox 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}" 
 Visibility="{Binding Path=Collection.Count, 
 Converter={StaticResource HideWhenZero}}"
/>
```

Comment: Didn't realize Count was observable. Thanks !